# Fire program when the user double clicks the right click of mouse

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want the following program to run and insert a shape when the user double clicks the mouse button. What event do I use and where should I use it?

```
Sub CurosrXY_Pixels(Sel As Word.Selection)
Dim shp As Word.Shape

Set shp = ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, fcnXCoord(Sel), fcnYCoord(Sel), 20#, 16#, Sel.Range)
With shp.TextFrame.TextRange
    .Font.Name = "Arial"
    .Font.Size = 7
    .Font.Bold = False
    .Paragraphs.FirstLineIndent = 0
    .Paragraphs.RightIndent = -10
    .Paragraphs.LeftIndent = -10
    .Paragraphs.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
    .Text = 11
End With
shp.LockAspectRatio = msoCTrue
End Sub

Function fcnXCoord(Sel As Word.Selection) As Double
fcnXCoord = Sel.Information(wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage)
End Function

Function fcnYCoord(Sel As Word.Selection) As Double
fcnYCoord = Sel.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The question title states "double click the right click of mouse". The actual question states "when user double click the mouse button". It's therefore unclear what you mean, **however**...

Word has **no** event for *double-clicking* the **right** mouse button, only for the left mouse button. That Word event is [WindowBeforeDoubleClick](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa211902(v%3Doffice.11)), an application-level event. See the documentation for information about the event and an example how to use it.

If you're unfamiliar with using VBA application-level events, see the documentation [Using Events with the Application Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2003/aa211915(v=office.11)).

If you run into problems with your event code, you can ask in a question.